# Password validation not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to get the match term to trigger to cause any type of form validation. Right now even if the passwords are different it will not show that the passwords do not match. Any reason this may be. I provide [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-1vux7x) and simple code as your reference. Hope you all can help me to settle my problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="changepwd(userForm)">
    <h2 mat-dialog-title class="dialog-form-title" class="dialog-form-title">CHANGE PASSWORD</h2>
    <div mat-dialog-content col-md-12>
      <mat-error *ngIf="changePasswordForm.hasError('notSame')">
        Passwords do not match
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="errorMessage" class="ctrl-msg">
        {{errorMessage}}
      </mat-error>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CurrentPassword">Current Password</label>
            <input matInput type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="currentPassword" >
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newPassword">New Password</label>
            <input matInput type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="newPassword" minlength="5">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="verifyPassword">Repeat Password</label>
            <input matInput type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="verifyPassword" inlength="5">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
        <div mat-dialog-actions class="dialog-form-footer text-center">

            <div class="clearfix"><button mat-flat-button class="chg-button">Change</button></div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.createForm();
    }

  createForm() {
   this.changePasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    newPassword: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    verifyPassword: ["", [Validators.required]]
    }, {
      validator:this.passwordValidator
    });
}

passwordValidator(form: FormGroup) {
  const condition = form.get('password').value !== form.get('confirmPassword').value;

  return condition ? { passwordsDoNotMatch: true} : null;
}

getErrorPassword() {
  console.log(this.changePasswordForm.get('newPassword').hasError('minLength'))
  return this.changePasswordForm.get('newPassword').hasError('required') ? 'Field is required' :
  this.changePasswordForm.get('newPassword').hasError('minLength') ? 'Password needs to be at least 5' : '';
}

getErrorConfirm(){
  return  this.changePasswordForm.get('verifyPassword').hasError('required') ? 'Field is required': '';
}

onSubmit(post) {
      console.log(post)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom Validator you have assigned passwordsDoNotMatch object for unmatched password, and you are trying to access "notSame" on your template

**Try this:**

```
<mat-error *ngIf="changePasswordForm.hasError('passwordsDoNotMatch')">
        Passwords do not match
 </mat-error>
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-hosyom)

Answer (score 1):

***Hi Add One Export Class for your matcher***

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
      isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        const invalidCtrl = !!(control && control.invalid && control.parent.dirty);
        const invalidParent = !!(control && control.parent && control.parent.invalid && control.parent.dirty);

        return (invalidCtrl || invalidParent);
      }
    }
```

***Add this into constructor***

```
 this.changePasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      newPassword: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]],
      verifyPassword: ['']
    }, { validator: this.checkPasswords });
```

*this is password check or checker function which tell you is  your password password or not*

```
checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) { // here we have the 'passwords' group
    let pass = group.controls.newPassword.value;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.verifyPassword.value;

    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true }
  }
```

Demo you can find here with your code  that i update for password and confirm password matcher only

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-g8zsa7